Compatibility of `size_t` in a binary stream
I write binary files, and want to be sure that I always read correct data back regardless the compiler/platform. In order to achieve that, I wrote a class that encapsulates a std::fstream, and all basic types have separate read/write operators with casts. For example:
BinaryFile& operator << (const int value)
{
    file << static_cast<int32_t>(value);
    return *this;
}
BinaryFile& operator << (const long value)
{
    file << static_cast<int64_t>(value);
    return *this;
}

The static cast should make software and datafiles compatible regardless the compiler/platform.
The type size_t (which is a typedef) seems to be problematic however. It must be at least 16 bits according to the standard, so it can be 32 bit on one platform and 64 bit on another. I cannot make additional read/write operators for it like above, because size_t is based on some basic type (unsigned long long for example) that already has its own operator and the compiler then complains that the operator for that type is duplicated.
What I not want to do is to cast a size_t myself every time I read/write it:
MyBinaryFile << static_cast<uint64_t>(some_vector.size());

Is there a way to 'catch' the size_t case so I can convert it to uint64_t and have compatible binary files? Or is a solution to convert all 'known' 32-bits like int also to 64 bit so we're always safe? Or do I see things completely wrong here?
Edit: sorry for some confusion in above text (see comments below, hope I understand them correctly), I was typing things out of my head. Actually I do not use the << operator in my own operator but write to file as follows:
BinaryFile& operator << (const int value)
{
    int32_t to_file = static_cast<int32_t>(value);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&to_file), sizeof(to_file))
    return *this;
}


I would settle for the fixed width type capable of holding the largest number you expect your size_t to ever have to care about. I usually go for uint32_t since I suspect it's the most portable of the fixed width types and it's usually capable of holding the lengths of my longest arrays.

static-casting int to int32_t is not guaranteed to be correct unless you have some preprocessor checks that conditionally enable this cast.

You can't distinguish it by type, because size_t is an alias for one of the unsigned integer types. Maybe the fstream interface with <<  is not the right tool for the job. Wouldn't it work better with having named methods like write_size() etc.?

In the C++ standard library, operator<< operates on text files. Using it for binary files will be, at best, confusing.

int can also be any size >=16bit and long can also be any type >=32bit. I do not see where you get the mapping from or what its purpose is supposed to be, e.g. on many platforms int32_t is just an alias for int anyway.

If you have code that must be size-compatible between different architectures, then it must not use std::size_t. It must use one of the intXX_t types from the start. The same is true for int, long, etc. On the other hand, overloading << should be done on int, long, long long (+ potentially char, short and unsigned variants) only, so that no types overlap in the overloads and so that every alias is guaranteed to be overloaded.

@PeteBecker the << operator on streams is used for text, there's nothing wrong with overloading it to do other things on other classes. << writing binary data when used on a class called BinaryFile isn't very surprising

@TedLyngmo: but you then have no control on std-lib functions that return size_t? It may be a typedef of unsigned int, unsigned long or unsigned long long. That means that all 3 of them should be casted to uint32_t or to uint64_t. Maybe better to choose 64 bit because I'm not sure what casting will do from 64 bit std::string::npos=-1 to 32 bit?

@AndyG: I do not understand your comment. Can you explain a little more what might go wrong?

@user17732522: i understand, I have overloads for all those types. Plus overloads for string and vectors, in there I first cast the size() from size_t to uint64_t before writing to get my compatibility there.

@JeroenBoschma I still don't understand the type mapping you are doing. None except the (u)intXX_t types have any guarantee on their size. You can't write a long as int64_t to a file and load it back into a long, because long may be only 32bit on another platform. std::size_t is exactly the same. Also, on different platforms endianese may differ, so that even using the same fixed-size type is not sufficient. All of that is why proper serialization is used.

@JeroenBoschma I'm saying that int is not always the same as int32_t, so static casting from int to int32_t may result in incorrect behavior. int is always at least 16 bits per the standard, but other than that, it's architecture specific. You could have a theoretical architecture with 17 bit integers, or 33 bit integers (however implausible), or even 64 bit integers, and any size larger than 32 bits would result in truncation upon casting to int32_t. Additionally, int32_t is not even guaranteed to be available in all implementations.

@user17732522 @AndyG The idea was to have a cast to a standard type intxx_t when writing  that is able to correctly hold the written value, and then cast back when reading. That may result in casting int/long/etc. to int64_t if we assume these basic types are never larger than 64 bit, so the roundtrip casting should be correct then. That then means that I should never use casting to/from 32 bit as in my question, but just use 64 bit. I wonder if there are (major) compilers that do not implement the optional intxx_t types, I see that as the least of my concerns now.

@JeroenBoschma "but you then have no control on std-lib functions" - You don't control the size of size_t so you will have to take control in order to store it portably. std::string::npos is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF if size_t is 64 bit. Cast it to uint32_t and you'll get 0xFFFFFFFF - which happens to be what npos is when size_t is 32 bit. The other way around doesn't work well though, so if size_t is 16 bit, going to uint32_t to store npos also needs tinkering. Why store npos though?

@TedLyngmo: npos was just an example, but I can imagine it is used somewhere to indicate a non-valid index or some other 'flag'. But if, for example, npos=-1 is unsigned 32 bit, I cast it to 64 bit, store it in file, read it back, cast back to 32 bit, and I get the same value I started with. I do not see a scenario where this needs tinkering. Intuitively it seem a correct round-trip.

@JeroenBoschma Ask yourself why you'd store it as an uint64_t in that scenario. On a platform where size_t is 64 bit, you still wouldn't be able to use more than 32 bits since the 32 bit npos made 0xFFFFFFFF unusable for a proper length. There will also potentially be 3 different npos values. 16, 32 and 64 ....

@TedLyngmo: I think I completely missed a scenario, probably what you describe. If I have a 32-bit size_t npos=-1, store it as 64-bit and then read it back on a platform that has a 64 bit npos then things go wrong because I do not get the value -1 back... Seems that I must be sure that every variable I need to write to file already is a (u)intxx_t type so no casts are done. Thanks for your time...

FWIW, the usual way to do this is just to have named member functions. (This is an application of "When should you give two things the same name?" — the answer is "basically never, unless there's a technical reason to do so.")
For example, you could have
struct BinaryFile {
  BinaryFile& put32(int i) { return put32(unsigned(i)); }
  BinaryFile& put32(unsigned i) { ... }
  template<class T> BinaryFile& put32(T) = delete; // forbid put32 of any other type

  BinaryFile& put64(long i) { ... }
  BinaryFile& put64(long long i) { ... }
  BinaryFile& put64(unsigned long i) { ... }
  BinaryFile& put64(unsigned long long i) { ... }
  template<class T> BinaryFile& put64(T) = delete; // forbid put64 of any other type

  BinaryFile& putsize(size_t i) { ... }
  template<class T> BinaryFile& putsize(T) = delete; // forbid putsize of any other type
};

BinaryFile bf;
bf.put64(myInt64).put32(myInt).putsize(myVec.size());

This still doesn't prevent people from accidentally-or-deliberately using put64 on a size_t —
size_t mySize;
unsigned long long myULL;
bf.put64(mySize);  // You want to forbid this...
bf.put64(myULL);   // ...while still permitting this!

— but sadly that's impossible, because size_t and unsigned long long are literally the same type (on your typical 64-bit platform).

This should probably use BinaryFile& put32(auto&&) = delete; because for an argument of a type that is immovable and non-copyable but has an operator int, put32 would still be called (via implicit conversion to int), and you're presumably trying to avoid that.

Also, you can avoid writing separate overloads if you write something like putsize(std::same_as<std::size_t> auto i).

@JanSchultke: OK, you scared me for a moment there, but I think you're wrong about that immovable/non-copyable type with an operator int. Godbolt. If you give type deduction a MoveOnly lvalue and ask it to deduce auto, it will still deduce MoveOnly; type deduction won't fail, so we won't fall back to the one taking int. But if you prove me wrong there, I'll credit you in the resulting blog post! ;)
